# "With an (instrument)" and "by (instrument)"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, differences, prepositions, by-with

"We forced the door ***with a jimmy***" is idiomatic whereas "The door was forced ***by jimmy***" (Note there is no article after 'by' in this sentence) is also idiomatic. However, "We forced the door ***by jimmy***" is not. I wonder whether one or the other is idiomatic is based on the passive-active difference. I can't assess whether the following sentences are idiomatic, as I'm a non-native speaker. If you could please help me with this, I'd be very much obliged.

---

[1-a] We drew lines with a straight edge.

[1-b] Lines were drawn by straight edge.

---

[2-a] We held the unknown object with the tongs we found in the lab.

[2-b] The unknown object was held by the tongs we found in the lab.

---

[3-a] We ate the beans with chopsticks.

[3-b] The beans were eaten by chopsticks.

---

[4-a] We cleaned the room with a broom and a mop.

[4-b] The room was cleaned by broom and mop.

---

[5-a] We cut the paper with such a peculiar instrument.

[5-b] The paper was cut by such a peculiar instrument.

---

[6-a] We measured the length of the rope with a ruler.

[6-b] The length of the rope was measured by ruler.

---

Comment: *By* focusses the attention on the word after it. So, 3b is wrong; the beans were actually eaten by us. Similarly, 4b suggests the Sorceror's Apprentice, with a broom and mop working on their own; 1b and 6b are actually better than 1a and 6a, to my ear.

Comment: @TimLymington: I don't buy your reasoning on 3b. By that logic you might just as well parse 3a to mean *we ate the chopsticks* **as well as** *the beans*.

Comment: @Fumble: You are wrong. Tim is correct. This isn't an issue of logic. "The beans were eaten by chopsticks" makes it seem like the chopsticks ate the beans. This has nothing to do with 3a.

Comment: @MrHen: I don't get that. If logic isn't involved, we can substitute *John* for *chopsticks*; he could certainly join in the repast.

Comment: @Fumble; It's disingenuous to assume *chopsticks* is the same as *the chopsticks*.

Comment: @TymLymington: In: *We ate the beans with almonds,* the sentence is grammatically correct, and there is absolutely no doubt about its meaning.

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I have no clue what distinguishes an idiomatic from a non-idiomatic sentence in your first examples. I would say that *"We forced the door with a jimmy."* is in no way idiomatic, and that *"by jimmy"* is idiomatic in either neither or both of the other two sentences. (I love being able to use *either neither or both* here.)

Comment: @Peter Shor: I really need to think about that *either neither or both!* You being a maths man I suppose the logic/semantic content is trivial in the extreme, but it's not *that* unusual in the "real" world, where I often use *and/or* as shorthand for *either or both*. I just can't think of an equivalent to include *neither*.

Comment: ...having duly thunk, I shall be ready for my first public airing of *and/or/nor* at the first plausible opportunity!

Answer (score 1):

"We forced the door with a jimmy" isn't really idiomatic because *jimmy* is a word that means:

> a short crowbar used by a burglar to force open a window or door

Nothing else about the sentence is being used abnormally or in a manner that couldn't be solved by a dictionary.

Furthermore, my ear doesn't consider "we forced the door by jimmy" normal usage and it sounds funny. I have never heard it before and *jimmy* isn't being used in a typical sense. The more common way to say this is:

> We jimmied the door

As for your list, these are the sentences I find unusual or awkward:

- [1-b] Lines were drawn by straight edge.
- [3-b] The beans were eaten by chopsticks.
- [4-b] The room was cleaned by broom and mop.
- [6-b] The length of the rope was measured by ruler.

These are all fine:

- [1-a] We drew lines with a straight edge.
- [2-a] We held the unknown object with the tongs we found in the lab.
- [3-a] We ate the beans with chopsticks.
- [4-a] We cleaned the room with a broom and a mop.
- [5-a] We cut the paper with such a peculiar instrument.
- [6-a] We measured the length of the rope with a ruler.
- [2-b] The unknown object was held by the tongs we found in the lab.
- [5-b] The paper was cut by such a peculiar instrument.

Comment: Thanks, MrHen. How about if I use 'crowbar' instead for 'jimmy' for the sentences I used in the question?

Comment: It would still seem off if you used crowbar.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure here is **[action] USING [implement]**.

It seems to me "with" can almost always substitute for "using".

I think substituting "by" becomes more acceptable the more closely the speficied action and implement are associated, *provided* such usage doesn't invite misinterpretation. The passive voice of OP's (b) examples could be taken to mean the implement is the *active agent* causing the action to take place at all, which is why these forms are probably best avoided.

(I'm not sure how to reconcile *I wash my socks by hand* with this position)

**LATER**: I'm now coming to the conclusion "by" forms are [idiomatic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiomatic) (contrary to OP, I'm sure the "with" form are not). If nothing else, that solves the problem of how to wash my socks!

Comment: I wonder you might still take the sentence to mean the implement after the 'by' was the active agent causing the action even if you didn't see 'a(n)' before the tool. To my non-native ear, without 'a(n)' it sounds as though it were made the noun representing the function(s) of the implement.

Comment: @Sssamy: Per my "later" update, if we accept that the "by" forms are at least *somewhat idiomatic*, that might explain why they don't seem "quite right" to you. I'm supposing you have no such misgivings about *using a*, or *with a* (note that I think native speakers would never use *by a* in any of these examples).

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers. I'm sorry as I am very new to this forum, and a non-native speaker, I have had a hard time following what you've kindly tried to explain to me. Are you now saying the 'with' forms are not natural at all? (clarification: I unwittingly omitted 'if' after 'wonder' in my last comment) I tried to come across the notation that I've felt "'by' + 'implement' without 'a/an'" would make itself sound like the 'implement' is not anymore a tool but it is now abstract, representing its functionality.

Comment: Note your explanation before the 'later' note makes a whole lot of sense to me. I thoroughly like the idea. (I couldn't add this to my last message because the total number of letters went over the limit)

Comment: @Sssamy: Well I hope my 'later' addition isn't something we need to disagree on. *Idioms* are usages falling outside standard grammar and/or semantic interpretation, which doesn't apply to "with" or "using". But with the "by" versions, although they are normally easy enough to understand, I think it would be hard for a non-native speaker to know which ones are grammatically acceptable (even for a native speaker, in some cases! :)

Comment: Gee, I just realized that by 'idiomatic' you mean 'of the features of idioms,' not 'natural.' I see. That solves my query, FumbleFingers! Thanks. I hope '@FumbleFingers' will appear this time. I couldn't last time. I don't see how it won't come out in my comment.

Comment: @Sssamy: You dont need (at sign)FumbleFingers on comments against *my* Answers (or Question) - the system knows it's me, so I get notification in my inbox automatically. Just lately they tweaked the system to delete such superfluous text when you make the post. But you *do* need it if you want to catch anyone else who also commented, but isn't the actual author (you can only have *one* name like that in any single comment).

Comment: The brochure was printed by laser printer.

I took a close look at this laser printer sentence, which they say is natural elsewhere, and read the messages here and there again. This does not cover all; it's merely one example condition, but it looks as though the key could be how the instrument after 'by' can behave as if it were a human, or a thing that could work on its own --- personified. The more automatic the instrument is, the more natural the sentence could be. What do you think?

[1] That fabric was made by weaving machine, not by hand.

Comment: [2] That freightage was transported by helicopter. (This may not stand idiomatic. 'by auto-pilot helicopter' may be better)
[3] Those sushi were made by automatic sushi-making machine.

Comment: @Sssamy: Despite lack of interest from ELU at large, this Q is turning out to be a bit of a conundrum. *The paper was cut by a peculiar instrument*, for example, would be fine. But you definitely *can't* discard the "a" there! Why, exactly? To be honest, I'm not keen on your "sushi" one without "an" either, but that may be just me.